# ASP.NET Set Page Title from Code Behind

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am creating data driven pages using ASP.NET C# and want to dynamically set the page title using code behind

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/FLMaster.master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="legal-expenses-insurance-news-item.aspx.cs" Inherits="legal_expenses_insurance_news_legal_expenses_insurance_news_item" %>
```

I have tried using the separate title tags lower down in the page but this didn't work either.  Can anyone advise how to do this.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

```
using System;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace MyApplication
{
    public partial class _Default : Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Title = "Title of my page";
        }
    }
}
```

You can modify the Page title like above from your **aspx.cs** (the code behind file).

If you want to do this directly in your **.aspx** file, try this:

```
<% this.Title = "Some Title" %>
```

This works if you correctly set your `Language = "C#"` in your `@Page` directive, which I see you did.

[**Page class reference from MSDN**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Answer (score 8):

The `Page` has a [`Title` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.title%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.Title = "Title";
}
```

Comment: Using the Title property of Page requires a header control on the page. (e.g. head runat="server" / ).

Answer (score 8):

You should remove the Title="" from the aspx page. It will override the Title set in your code-behind

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/FLMaster.master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="legal-expenses-insurance-news-item.aspx.cs" Inherits="legal_expenses_insurance_news_legal_expenses_insurance_news_item" %>
```

```
    
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            this.Title = "Title";
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

I know that this is an old thread, but I found that Page.Title couldn't always be overriden, but Page.Header.Title could (mostly)... so my solution for dynamic title tags from the Master codebehind is:

```
    if (Page.Header != null)
    {
        if (Page.Header.Title == null || !Page.Header.Title.Contains("COMPANYNAME"))
        {
            var otitle = Page.Header.Title;
            if (otitle == null || otitle.Length==0) {
                var textinfo = System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.TextInfo;
                otitle = textinfo.ToTitleCase(this.Parent.GetType().Name.Replace("_"," ").Replace("aspx",""));
            }
            Page.Header.Title = "COMPANYNAME" + " - " + otitle;
        }
        Page.Header.Title = Page.Header.Title.Replace("COMPANYNAME", Auth.getSetting("companyName"));
    }
```