# Kentico meta data information

Tags: kentico

Using a Head HTML code webpart, i'm adding OG meta data:

```html
<meta property="og:title" content="{% CurrentDocument.DocumentName #%}" />
<meta property="og:type" content="article" />
<meta property="og:url" content="{% CurrentDocument.AbsoluteURL #%}" />
<meta property="og:description" content="{% StripTags(CurrentDocument.Summary) #%}" />
```

How would i then change the current title and standard description tag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On your parent page for example `/blog` set the page title and description under Properties>Metadata using a macro. Then on the sub-pages let it automatically inherit that content.  Take a look at this macro for the page description:

`{% if(CurrentDocument.ClassName == "cms.blogpost"){BlogPostSummary}else{"Kentico MVP Brenden Kehren talks about Kentico how tos, provides code samples and education and just life in general."} #%}`

What's happening here is the macro is checking the current page's class and if it's a blog post, then it uses the `BlogPostSummary` field and sets the description using that, otherwise if it's a blog or blog month, it uses the other text.

There should be no need to manually set those on each page unless you really have crazy SEO requirements.  Even if so, you can create fields in your page type for those and still dynamically set them vs. manually set each one under metadata.

Comment: Once again thanks. I extrapolated this for the Title tag too. you should do this for a living :)

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for changing title and description HTML tags by a web part or just configuring it for some page?

If you just want to configure title and description of the HTML page then you can just select the document in the **Pages** application and then go to **Properties -> Metadata**. Documentation for that is [here](https://docs.kentico.com/display/K9/Configuring+websites+for+SEO)

If you are looking to somehow change the title and description by a web part then you would actually need to develop a custom web part and access the current page title of the page in code behind. Something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21166468/asp-net-set-page-title-from-code-behind) works.

Comment: I have the meta data configurable, but in this instance, it's a selected transformation. OG meta is fine, but adding a second title and description tag will cause problems. 

I may have to create a custom .aspx and matching kentico template for this and do it that way. All good on that front, as i want to use the same things for a future blog section.

Answer (score 0):

Even using the selected item transformation, transformatted item is a page from your content tree and as such has the Properties -> Metadata section. Moreover, titles and descriptions are inherited by default so you can just change or odd macros to their parent and it changes the title and description for pages in your selected transformation.